# Solving $\sqrt{2}\times\sqrt{15}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve $$\sqrt{2}\times\sqrt{15}$$

Please explain in easy to follow steps

Comment: What one wants to solve are *equations* only. Perhaps you want to simplify this, or express the product as the square root of a single number? If your teacher asked you to “solve” this, then (s)he was being very imprecise.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: 
$\forall a,b\in\mathbb N$
$$\sqrt{a}\times\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$$

Now put $a=2$ , $b=15$ and see what you get!

Comment: So because the square roots of 2 and 15 are irrational (i.e. long ass numbers), i can write a and b to represent the square roots, and the answer is a x b?

Comment: @Eric $\sqrt a*\sqrt b=\sqrt{ab}$. Your values are $a=2,b=15.$